# Conflict between fancyhdr, truncate and xcolor packages

Tags: color, fancyhdr

With this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[fit, breakwords]{truncate}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\small\textsc{\color{blue}{\thechapter.\ #1}}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\small\textsc{\color{blue}{\thesection.\ #1}}}{}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\truncate{0.9 \textwidth}{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\truncate{0.9 \textwidth}{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\color{blue}\textsc{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand\headrule{\color{blue}%
    \rule{6.4cm}{.4pt}%
    \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
    \rule{6.4cm}{.4pt}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{This is a chapter title}
    \section{This is a section title}
    \Blindtext
    \section{This is a a very long section title that employs three lines of text.
             This is a a very long section title that employs three lines of text.} 
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

I am obtaining the problem shown in the image: after a long title that is truncated in a colored header, the color of the text changes as well. I would like it to keep it black.

[image: color problem]

Comment: Why do you add formatting to chapter- or sectionmark? It ought to be a part of the printing of header. `\small\scshape\color{blue}\truncate{... `. Chapter- and sectionmark should only contain the text part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `fancyhdr` problem.

As @daleif notes, you should not put the `\color` command in the `\chaptermark` or `\sectionmark`. *What I think that happens, is that the `\color` command that is written in a `\mark` in TeX's output leaks into the rest of the output.*

Update: after some experimenting I found that the problem is caused by the `\color` command inside the `\truncate` command. For some reason `\truncate` causes the `\color` command to escape from itself (perhaps because it cuts off the internal command that resets the color stack at the end). So the `\color` command should be outside of the `\truncate`.

In other words: (1) **Don't use `\color` commands in marks.** (2) **Don't use `\color` commands inside a `\truncate` argument.**

Here is a corrected version of your document. I made the following corrections:

- Moved the `\color` commands ofrom the `...mark`s into the headers
- Changed the `\headheight`, and made a corresponding change to
  `\textheight`.
- The `\headrule` was too long. I changed the explicit `\rule`s to `\hfillrule` so that they automatically get the right length.
- I put the `\color` commands outside of the `\truncate`. See above.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[fit, breakwords]{truncate}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\color{blue}\truncate{0.9 \textwidth}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\color{blue}\truncate{0.9 \textwidth}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\color{blue}\small\textsc{\thepage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand\headrule{\color{blue}%
    \hrulefill
    \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
    \hrulefill}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{This is a chapter title}
    \section{This is a section title}
    \Blindtext
    \section{This is a a very long section title that employs three lines of text.
             This is a a very long section title that employs three lines of text.} 
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank  you very much! It worked flawlessly!!